# Cannot alter table with LINQ TO SQL and stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql, stored-procedures

I have to alter the table `Statistic` when I add a new metric in the table `Metric` I add a column in table `Statistic`.

I used a stored procedure that allows me to alter the table `Statistic` so the code :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.addnewmetricInstat
(
    @MetricName varchar(254),
    @TypeMetric varchar(254)
)
AS
  IF (@TypeMetric='int')
  Begin
      alter table Statistic
      add @MetricName int null
  end
  ELSE if (@TypeMetric='string')
  begin
     alter table Statistic
     add @MetricName varchar(254) null
  end
```

Then I successfully called the stored procedure but the columns is not added. The code I used in C# for calling this stored procedure is:

```
using (DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext("Data Source=EMEA-TUN-WS0367\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Perfgas;Integrated Security=True"))
{
    db.addnewmetricInstat(metric.MetricName, metric.Type);
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Comment: Won't fix your problem, but thought you might want to know that you don't need to SubmitChanges, the SP will make a call directly on the database anyway.

Comment: Altering columns in the DB seems like a bad design - seems like you should have a 'statistics' table that you could add _rows_ to.  If you need them as columns in a result then you could pivot them in the report or app.

Comment: Make sure your parameters match with the ones provided. Can check it through `SQL Profiler`

Comment: add '@MetricName varchar(254)' null why this he signaling a mistake in @MetricName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you shoud not be trying to call the sp from your application until you have tested it in SSMS. That way you know if the problem is your call or the sp. It will save you much debugging time if you do this.

Your proc is the problem. You will need to use dynamic SQl for this. Right now you are trying to add a column called MetericName because you didn't use the variable. This would work once, but of course the second time you run it, you will get an error becasue teh column already exists.  However you can;t just throw a variable into an alter table statement, you must use dynamic SQL.

Comment: can you give more spécification or example and thank you because i am new in using sql server @HLGEM

Comment: everything you need to know about dynamic SQl before using it. http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Comment: 'Declare @ SQL VarChar(1000)

SELECT @ SQL = 'ALTER TABLE Statistic ADD ' + @type + ' INT'

Exec (@ SQL)'

Comment: MAke sure you read the part about sql injection before finalizing this.